# Изменение импортируемого файла в цикле

Tags: python

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
for i in range(5):
    from cookie import cookie_list
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы cookie менялось на cookie1, cookie2, cookie3… ?

Comment: А в чём смысл этого кода? Чего вы хотите сделать? Почему не выйдет импортировать всё, например.

Comment: если сделать так, как описано, то в итоге в коде останется только значение cookie_list из cookie4, поэтому можно сразу написать  ``from cookie4 import cookie_list``

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, только тут весь модуль импортируется:

```
import importlib

for i in range(5):
    importlib.import_module(f'cookie{i}')
```

Для получения конкретной переменной из модуля можно попробовать как-то так:

```
cookie_list = getattr(importlib.import_module(f'cookie{i}'), 'cookie_list')
```

Comment: а разве не останется в итоге только последняя импортированая cookie_list?

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну я же не знаю, что человеку нужно. Может это не весь код цикла и там дальше какая-то работа идёт с импортированным списком

Comment: а, ну это да, возможен такой вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib
for i in range(2):
    globals()[f'cookie_list_{i}'] = importlib.import_module(f"cookie{i}")
print(cookie_list_1)
```

если cookie1 это файл cookie1.py